# Move pointer with tail over curve in rapheljs,

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, raphael

I am going to create a curve on which a white colored pointer moves slowly, That pointer has long tail of boxes from opacity 1 to 0. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/6S8FH/) is a fiddle without animating of pointer. I am trying to move those boxes of pointer tail but they are loosing their distances. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/6S8FH/1/) is another step what I did for animation n what I am getting. How can I animate without loosing originality of the pointers like in first fiddle link?

Here is the animation code What I did

```
    var paper = Raphael(0,0, 1300,700);
var p=paper.path('M27,443Q159,708,342,370,500,60,640,370,800,700,940,445')
.attr({
    stroke:'#000',
    'stroke-width':10,
});
 Len = p.getTotalLength();
 paper.customAttributes.Along = function (v) {
            var Point = Curve.getPointAtLength(v * Len);

            return {
                transform: "t" + [Point.x, Point.y] + "r" + Point.alpha
            };
        };

var arr=[],i
for(i=0;i<500;i+=12){
    arr.push(
        paper.path(p.getSubpath(i,i+10)).attr({
            stroke:'#FFF',
            'stroke-width':10,
            opacity:(i/800),
            along:0
        }))
}
var x=0;

function move(){
    var tmp;
    for(var d=arr.length-1;d>0;d--){
        if(d==(arr.length-1)){
            tmp=arr[arr.length-1].attr('path').toString();
            arr[arr.length-1].attr({path:p.getSubpath(x,x+5)});
        }
        else if(d==0){
            arr[i]=tmp;
        }            
        else{
            var t=arr[d].attr('path').toString();
            arr[d].attr({
                path:tmp
            });
            tmp=t;
        }
    }

    x++;
    if(x>1200)return;
    setTimeout(move,1)
}


move()
```